# How yt-dlp provides faster search results

Tags: python-3.x, yt-dlp

Below is a search code

```py
def search(query, max_results=5):
    # Parameters for calling yt-dlp
    command = [
            'yt-dlp',
            'ytsearch{}:{}'.format(max_results, query),
            '--dump-json', 
            '--default-search', 'ytsearch',
            '--no-playlist', '--no-check-certificate', '--geo-bypass'
        ]
    try:
        # Get the output and analyze it
        output = subprocess.check_output(command).decode('utf-8')
        videos = [json.loads(line) for line in output.splitlines()]
        # Simplify the results for displaying to the user
        simplified_results = []
        for video in videos:
            simplified_results.append({
                "title": video.get("title", "N/A"),
                "url": video.get("webpage_url", "N/A"),
                "origin_url": video.get("original_url", "N/A"),
                "duration": str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=video.get("duration", 0))),
                "uploader": video.get("uploader", "N/A")
            })

        return simplified_results

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return []
```

This is the command I use to call yt-dlp, and then get the output and convert it into data, but yt-dlp is too slow whether it is called on the console or through subprocess. Below are the parameters I use

```py
command = [
            'yt-dlp',
            'ytsearch{}:{}'.format(max_results, query),
            '--dump-json', 
            '--default-search', 'ytsearch',
            '--no-playlist', '--no-check-certificate', '--geo-bypass'
        ]
```

```
yt-dlp ytsearch{max_results}:{query} --dump-json --default-search ytsearch --no-playlist --geo-bypass
```

I don't need to download the video, just get his webpage url, but it takes 11 seconds for just five results

I want to get results faster, is there any good way?

Comment: Execute the requests in parallel / asynchronously?

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: secondly, as a side comment. Putting an entire block of code is a `try-except` block will prevent catching potentially important errors.

Comment: That's why I  moved on to another library, `ytdl-core` (Node, not Python). Just 2-3 seconds for a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
command = [
            "yt-dlp",
            "ytsearch{}:{}".format(max_results, query),
            "--dump-json", 
            "--default-search", "ytsearch",
            "--no-playlist", "--no-check-certificate", "--geo-bypass",
            "--flat-playlist", "--skip-download", "--quiet", "--ignore-errors"
        ]
```

Add `--flat-playlist`, `--skip-download`, `--quiet`, `--ignore-errors` to speed up, Reduced from 11 seconds to over 1.6 seconds